# Regression intepretation through standard deviation

Tags: regression, standard-deviation

I am having an OLS regression where I come to the resultS intepretation stating something in the lines of "an one employee increase in the company personnel leads on average to an increase of $20.000 company profit". However, talking with a professor he advised me do the intepratation in standard deviation like "an one standard deviation increase in company personnel leads to X increase in profits".

Looking online i did not find a proper method on how to do that, can anyone provide me with any info on how the intepratations works?

Comment: @eSurfsnake so i would check the standard deviation of the x coefficient and then use that to explain possible outcomes on y? Kind of like you did in you post?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to clarify what the professor is saying.  What I hear you saying is that, in an ols regression with profit as the dependent (y) variable, and employees as the dependent (or X variable), the slope of the regression line is $20,000 in profit increase (y variable) per unit of one increase in the x variable.

Usually, we think about standard deviation being a creature of the y variable, not the x.  For example, the standard deviation of that slope estimate might be $5,000.  Then, we would be 67% certain adding one employee adds something between 15,000-25,000, a 95% chance of adding 10,000 to 30,000 (2 standard deviations), etc.

It doesn’t make much sense to talk about srandard deviations ofvthe x valu